# How to handle transaction fees in auctions absed on smartcontracts in blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I am writing a smart contract to list NFT's for auction  and the flow I am following is of `automichub` which deals with NFT's on Wax chain. What they are doing is everytime a bidder place's a bid, that amount is deducted from the wallet's balance and in the end of the bidding cycle if that was the winning bid the NFT is awarded to the bidder else the amount if refunded back to the wallet.

In this flow I am assuming that they must be transferring the balance on their contract and later refunding back the amount to every bidder who lost. Now coming to my problem, I am going to deploy this contract on `Ethereum` network and the gas fee's is going to be a huge concern for me.

If I get 100 bids on one nft and I get a total of 1 `Ethereum` in those 100 bids and now when the contract has to return the coins back to the remaining 99 users the gas fees is going to be a major concern.

So I'd like to know am I approaching this problem correctly or is there a better way to handle this?

Any help / comment is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your contract is providing a service for people. Even if it is not a commercial service and you are not taking any commision, it is OK to ask for a maintenance fee. Unless of course you are going all pro-bono.

Some options:

- Compute average gas usage of your process, anytime (or the first time) someone bids, ask bid + fee
- Deduct from seller's payment. Once the auction is complete, you are going to send the highest bid to the seller. Deduct the total fee from that payment